# On the maximal solutions of an ODE: how to find a Maximal Interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation $$y'+y=xy^3$$ and find its maximal solutions (We are looking for $y$ as a function of $x$).

It is easy to see that the identically zero function over $\mathbb{R}$ is a maximal solution of the equation.

In order to get non trivial solutions, (we make some arrangements and) we substitute, by making $z=\frac{1}{y^2}$ to get the equation $$v'-2v=-2x,$$

whose solutions are the functions (defined over $\mathbb{R}$) of the form $$z=x+\frac{1}{2}+ke^{2x},$$
where $k$ is a real number. Now, given $y$, a non-zero solution of the original equation, it must be the case that $\frac{1}{y^2}$ is a solution of the second equation, i.e. $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac{1}{y^2}=x+\frac{1}{2}+ke^{2x} \tag{I}.$$

However, fixed $k$ this only makes sense for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$k \gt e^{-2x} \Big(-x-\frac{1}{2}\Big)$$ and then $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}+ke^{2x}}}.$$ So in order to find the maximal solutions of the equations all we are left is solve the equation $\mathrm{(I)}$. My question is: how do we prove that given $k$ the solution to $\mathrm{(I)}$ is an interval and how do I find that maximal interval?

Answer (score 0):

HINT
To check your calculation try this substitution:

$y =z \dot e^{-x}$

So, 
$z' \dot e^{-x} =  xz^3e^{-3x}$ => $\frac{z'}{z^3} = \frac{x}{e^{2x}}$